GitHub Actions Job Fails with Exit Code 1 Despite All Laravel PHPUnit Tests Passing
I'm encountering an issue with my GitHub Actions workflow where all my Laravel PHPUnit tests pass, but the job still fails with exit code 1. I have tried adjusting the workflow, but I can't figure out why the job fails despite the tests running successfully.
My GitHub Workflow:
name: Run Tests

on:
 push:
   branches:
    - main

jobs:
 tests:
  name: Run tests
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  env:
    DOCKER_USER: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}
    DOCKER_PASS: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASS }}

  steps:
    - name: Checkout Code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Decode and create .env file
      run: |
        echo "${{ secrets.ENV_FILE_BASE64 }}" | base64 --decode > .env

    - name: Login to DockerHub
      run: docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASS

    - name: Build Docker images
      run: docker compose build

    - name: Run Containers
      run: docker compose up -d

    - name: Run tests
      run: docker compose exec -it backend php artisan test

    - name: Tear down Docker Compose
      run: docker compose down

Error Output:

Does anyone have suggestions for why this is happening, or how I can get more detailed insights into the cause of the failure?

Did you get any warnings when the test command was executed?

Try running without -it flags.
